# Unable to pull value off array of objects in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I have a React project where I am returned an array of objects from an API. After successfully setting this array of objects to the state in a class component, I want to use a specific value, for example:

I get back [{bar: 2, foo: 13}, {bar: 22, foo: 3}, {bar: 9, foo: 1}].

I then want to say pull off the 2 from bar: 2.

And while I can pull of particular objects, for example {bar: 2, foo: 13}, I cannot pull off bar or foo.

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props);

   this.state = {
   videos: []
  };
 }


componentDidMount() {
axios
  .get("https://abc.herokuapp.com/videos/videoapi")
  .then(response => response)   
  .then(data => this.setState({ videos: data.data}));
}

render() {
const videos = this.state.videos;
console.log(videos); //returns array with 4 objects 
console.log(videos[0]); //returns object with 6 properties
console.log(videos[0].embed); //TypeError: Cannot read property 'embed' of 
undefined
```

Comment: is this just an async problem since you aren't checking if `this.state.videos.length > 0` before diving in?

Comment: Does `console.log(videos[0]);` return an *object* or a *string*?  You may need to `JSON.parse(videos[0])`. Check `typeof(videos[0])`, etc

Comment: Thanks, turned out to be an async issue and was fixed by checking the length. However, I'm not sure I totally understand. It seems that if I am able to console.log the entire object, I shouldn't have any difficulty pulling off individual properties.

Comment: It might be that you're mixing up logs from different renders. In the first render, `videos[0]` is `undefined`, so logging it would look like you're not logging anything. Then, in a later render, you would see the data. Not sure, but it's a possibility.